# How can I use the scapy module to send a request and accept three answers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, scapy

I am trying to use the scapy module to ask the 4.2.2.4 server for some url IP addresses.

Most of the requests for inquiries will only get one answer, which may have one or more IP addresses. But "facebook.com" is different. The server will give me three answers, and each answer has an IP address.

Why is this happening? How can I get all three answers in my python program? I tried the sr() and sr1() functions, but they all only get one answer.

My code:

```
from scapy.all import *
url = 'facebook.com'
server = '4.2.2.4'
result1, unanswer = sr(IP(dst=server) / UDP() / DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname=url, qtype='A', qclass='IN')))
result2 = sr1(IP(dst=server) / UDP() / DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname=url, qtype='A', qclass='IN')))
```

The results I got (part of the answer):

> \an        \
>
> |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
>
> |  rrname    = 'facebook.com.'
>
> ......
>
> |  rdata     = '173.252.103.64'

The result I got with wireshark:
[image: The result I got with wireshark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

You can use the `multiple` keyword argument in `sr()`:

```
sr([...], multiple=True)
```